# How Do You Build and Test An App the Same Way it Gets Deployed by Apple App Store

Tags: maui

I have an app that I thought was done - it was working fine in both debug and release builds from my local mac to my iPhone.  I put it up on the Apple App Store to begin testing with Test Flight, and now I'm getting nothing but errors, all of which seem related to JIT activities that aren't at all obvious.  This is a terrible way to try and debug an app now - trying fixes and updating my build on the App Store.  So how can I build and test my app locally with whatever kind of AOT switch is used when deployed from the Apple App Store?

Comment: generally speaking, testing on a device with a Release build should be the same as an App Store build.  But it depends on how you have your build configs setup

Comment: Boy I wish that were so but I've had nothing but pulling my hair out experiences for the last 24 hours. And still continuing to try and fix these mystery errors.

Comment: Testflight is the closest

Comment: Yeah it's the only. The problem is that it's not a debugger.  You have to create build, upload to app store, download to your phone, and add a bunch of exception handlers and message boxes to try and figure out the errors.  It is absolutely ridiculous - maui is not a viable product in my opinion.